# What are some ways to add a video to a question?

Tags: support, youtube-embed

I would like to ask a question, and think it would be easiest to explain the problem by showing a video.

What are some ways to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can link to a video by adding it [as a normal link](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/editing-help#links):

> ```
> As you can see in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FaMTedT6P0I)...
> ```

You can also embed a YouTube video in place by putting a bare link to the video in its own line:

> ```
> This is what I tried:
>
> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FaMTedT6P0I
> ```

Which produces this:

Comment: Do we have a rep restriction on who can inline a youtube video?

Comment: @MBraedley Nope.  Even unregistered 1-rep users can inline videos.  It happens fairly often.